# Vue good table firstSortType and initialSortBy not working

Tags: vue.js, vue-good-table

I am using vue-good-table for my tables. I tried to sort by data in descending using `firstSortType` and `initialSortBy` its not at all sorting the table. It always sorts the table in ascending order. My table looks something like this

[image]

I tried `firstSortType` like this

```
  {
          label: "Tracking Number",
          field: "docket_no",

          sortable: true,
          firstSortType: "desc"
        },
```

initialSortBy

```
<vue-good-table

              :columns="tableColumns1"
              :rows="shipments"
              :line-numbers="true"

              :search-options="{
    enabled: true,
       placeholder: 'Type to search',
  }"

    :pagination-options="{
    enabled: true,
     mode: 'pages',
     
  }"

   :sort-options="{
enabled: true,
initialSortBy: [

  {field: 'docket_no', type: 'desc'}
],
```

}"
/>

When I try to use initialSortBy its showing me this error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'setInitialSort' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lot of research I was able to solve this by adding a v-if,

```
<vue-good-table 
  v-if="rows && rows.length"
  :rows="rows"
...
```